# Is any other saiyan as powerful as Goku after last transformation i. e. blue?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

Is any other saiyan as powerful as Goku after last transformation i.e. saiyan blue?

Comment: Give it five minutes.

Comment: Depends what your watching/reading Vegeta, Black and Kale are as strong or stronger than him in blue.